# Symbol of the tennis ball

Tags: pdftex, symbols, packages, amssymb

I have been looking for a few days a package that it contains a command/symbol to use with `pdfLaTeX`, without using `TikZ`, of the  **tennis ball**. I have seen *The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List* where there are symbols but I couldn't find anything.

Sure to have courteous and benevolent feedback I extend my greetings and thanks.

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=ball

Comment: @Sigur Thank you very much, if you see my recent questions I use the fontawesome package. But what is the command? Is there a command to write the symbol?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if those glyphs are in the package.

Comment: @Sigur no, :-( I've unfortunately seen them one by one.

Comment: Consider including as an image.

Comment: @Sigur I have a lot of pictures for my book and I wanted to avoid using this option. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: You can save it in a box and simply use this box.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, package `fontawesome` seems to be not longer maintained and therefore you can not add with LaTeX and this package an symbol for an ball into your document.

But you can use package `fontawesome5`.

The font shows the following ball symbols on the web page:

[image: balls on fontawesome5]

As you can see the symbol for an tennis ball is grey that means you have to **pay** for the **fontawesome5 pro font** to be able to use it. Only the black shown symbol are available in the free font version.

So you can try for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5} % <============================================

\begin{document}
\faTwitter

\faLinkedin

\faGithub

\faBasketballBall\ or \faIcon{basketball-ball} % <======================

\faBaseballBall\ or \faIcon{baseball-ball} % <==========================
\end{document}
```

with the resulting pdf:

[image: pdf]

Comment: Thank you so much with all your heart. I didn't know that there was the version 5 of fontawesome by Marcel Kruger which is very recent of June 7, 2019. In about ten minutes I will enter a question because with the code that interests me gives me an error that I can not remove.

Comment: Hi, kindest. On my long preamble I not can have, actually, the tennis ball :-((((. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501476/error-fontawesome5-on-a-specific-preamble. It's being worked on the very good user  Phelype Oleinik (see my comments), Probably there will be some problem with any parts of my book or conflict with some package.

Comment: @Sebastiano Be carefull, you can only use the black printed symbols with free fontawesome5. (`\faBaseballBall` or `\faBasketballBall` you can use). To be able to use `\faIcon{tennis-ball}` you need to have fontawesome 5 pro (that means you have to pay for that professional font ...  Do you use a lot of counters in your book? The linked comments shows an error message caused by too many used counters ...

Answer (score 14):

You can define a picture.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\newcommand\tennisBall{%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}%
  \begin{picture}(1,1)(-.5,-.5)
    \put(0,0){\circle{1}}
    \qbezier(0,-.49)(0,0)(.4825,-.0850)
    \qbezier(0,.49)(0,0)(-.4825,.0850)
  \end{picture}%
}
\begin{document}
\tennisBall
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Let's start responding in order of precedence. Meanwhile, I apologize for the delay in answering and I really appreciated your painstaking and detailed work. I may need to serve myself on another occasion. I reciprocate your answer and thank you for meeting another person (I had never received your answer). Thank you very much.  +1