# Vertical tennis ball into fancy new enumerate

Tags: enumerate, enumitem, fontawesome

Considering the related questions:

1. [Error fontawesome5 on a specific preamble](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501476/error-fontawesome5-on-a-specific-preamble);
2. [Symbol of the tennis ball](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501338/symbol-of-the-tennis-ball)

and this new style of fancy enumerate with the tennis balls with this MWE,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5,xcolor,lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}
\newcount\cnt
\cnt=1

\newbox\tennis
\setbox\tennis=\hbox{\faBaseballBall}

\def\numberlabel{%
  \ifnum\the\cnt>4\relax
  \else {\bfseries\small\sffamily[\the\cnt]}%
  \fi
}

\def\Iitem{%
  \item[%
    \smash{\raisebox{-.5em}{%
     \vbox{\baselineskip=10pt
      \hbox to \the\wd\tennis{\hss\numberlabel\hss}
      \hbox{%
        \ifnum\the\cnt=1{\color{green}{\faBaseballBall}}
        \else
          \ifnum\the\cnt=2{\color{orange}\faBaseballBall \,\faBaseballBall}
          \else
            \ifnum\the\cnt=3{\color{yellow}\faBaseballBall\,\faBaseballBall\,\faBaseballBall}
            \else
              \ifnum\the\cnt=4{\color{red}\faBaseballBall\,\faBaseballBall\,\faBaseballBall\,\faBaseballBall}
              \else{\sffamily\color{magenta}{\faBaseballBall\,\faBaseballBall\,\faBaseballBall\,\faBaseballBall\,\faBaseballBall}}
              \fi
            \fi
          \fi
        \fi}%
    }}}%
  ]%
  \advance\cnt by 1
}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\Iitem \lipsum[1] 
\Iitem \lipsum[1]  
\Iitem \lipsum[1]  
\Iitem \lipsum[1] 
\Iitem \lipsum[1]  
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Question:**

*how is it possible to put the balls in vertical position below the number?*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not really difficult with `xparse`. `;-)`

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5,xcolor,xparse,graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlist{nolistsep}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\tennis}{m}
 {
  \sebastiano_tennis:c { c@#1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \sebastiano_tennis:N
 {
  \smash
   {
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
    [\int_to_arabic:n { #1 }] \\
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ \__sebastiano_tennis:n { #1 } }
    \end{tabular}
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \sebastiano_tennis:N { c }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__sebastiano_tennis:n
 {
  \textcolor
   {
    \clist_item:Nn \c_sebastiano_tennis_clist
     {
      \int_mod:nn { #1 } { \clist_count:N \c_sebastiano_tennis_clist } + 1
     }
   }
   {
    \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { \faBaseballBall }
   }
 }
% make \tennis available to enumitem
\AddEnumerateCounter{\tennis}{\sebastiano_tennis:c}{[1]}
% define here your colors: the first in the list is actually the last used
\clist_const:Nn \c_sebastiano_tennis_clist {magenta,green,orange,yellow,red}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\tennis*,ref=\arabic*]
\item \lipsum[1][1-7]
\item \lipsum[1][1-7]
\item \lipsum[1][1-7]
\item \lipsum[1][1-7]
\item \lipsum[1][1-7]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: After the fifth item, the colors will cycle (unless new ones are added to the constant clist. Of course, it's up to the author to make so that the labels don't overlap.

Comment: "Si si come no :-).-) dire non è realmente difficile". For you it's all easy ahahah: easy to say but for me your code is stellar or spatial. I think I'm able to put on the bold and insert \sffamily. Just a curiosity. But if there is little text in the number 6, the tennis balls as are they distributed? Do they invade the number 7 of the enumeration?

Comment: @Sebastiano Of course the vertical ball set will overlap the next if there is not sufficient text to cover it. I took this just as a funny exercise, but I wouldn't recommend using it in a book.

Comment: I have to use them when I have a lot of text in the book we're doing. 

Answer (score 6):

Using `\rotatebox`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{
fontawesome5,
xcolor,lipsum,graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}
\newcount\cnt
\cnt=1

\newbox\tennis
\setbox\tennis=\hbox{\faBaseballBall}

\def\numberlabel{%
  \ifnum\the\cnt>4\relax
  \else {\bfseries\small\sffamily[\the\cnt]}%
  \fi
}

\def\Iitem{%
  \item[%
    \smash{\raisebox{-.5em}{%
     \vbox{\baselineskip=10pt
      \hbox to \the\wd\tennis{\hss\numberlabel\hss}
      \hbox{%
        \ifnum\the\cnt=1{\color{green}{\faBaseballBall}}
        \else
          \ifnum\the\cnt=2{\color{orange}\rotatebox{90}{\faBaseballBall \,\faBaseballBall}}
          \else
            \ifnum\the\cnt=3{\color{yellow}\rotatebox{90}{\faBaseballBall\,\faBaseballBall\,\faBaseballBall}}
            \else
              \ifnum\the\cnt=4{\color{red}\rotatebox{90}{\faBaseballBall\,\faBaseballBall\,\faBaseballBall\,\faBaseballBall}}
              \else{\sffamily\color{magenta}\rotatebox{90}{\faBaseballBall\,\faBaseballBall\,\faBaseballBall\,\faBaseballBall\,\faBaseballBall}}
              \fi
            \fi
          \fi
        \fi}%
    }}}%
  ]%
  \advance\cnt by 1
}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\Iitem \lipsum[1] 
\Iitem \lipsum[1]  
\Iitem \lipsum[1]  
\Iitem \lipsum[1] 
\Iitem \lipsum[1]  
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is very interesting :-) using \rotatebox. But there is a problem: the enumeration is not aligned with the start of a new item (paragraph). There is a shift in direction of the top. I have appreciate your work and the effort.

Comment: This is the right idea, but you need to adjust the `\raisebox` value proportionally to the number of balls. One idea is create a new length `\ballht` and then use `\setlength{\ballht}{\the\cnt ex}` inside `\item`. Then use `\raisebox{-2.7\ballht}` instead of `\raisebox{-.5em}`. The 2.7 value was determined by trial and error.

Comment: Also, since the balls are now vertical, the conditional inside the `\numberlabel` definition is no longer needed.